# Error #1241 subconsulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

¿Como crear dos subconsultas en `MySQL`? de manera eficaz y optimizado.

El código actual me lanza el error `#1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)` desde el *phpMyAdmin*.

- La primera subconsulta me calcula el total de clases disponibles.
- La segunda subconsulta deseo calcular el promedio y total de votos
  emitidos.

**Mi código:**

```
$sql = "SELECT video.title,video.icon,video.duration,video.url,video.author,level.level,
             (
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM `lessons`
                 WHERE video.ident_video = lessons.ident_video
             ),
             (   
                SELECT AVG(vote) AS avg_vote, COUNT(*) votos
                  FROM `coments`
                 WHERE video.ident_video = coments.ident_video
             )                  
          FROM `video` 
     LEFT JOIN `level` on video.ident_level = level.ident_level
         WHERE video.ident_state=? ORDER BY video.ident_video DESC LIMIT 5";
```

> Error:  error #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

**Tablas `SQL`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `level` (
  `ident_level` smallint(3) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `level` varchar(15) not null
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `state` (
  `ident_state` smallint(3) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `state` varchar(15) not null
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `video` (
  `ident_video` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  
  `title` varchar(255) not null,  
  `icon` varchar(100) not null,    
  `duration` varchar(10) not null,
  `url` varchar(100) not null unique,      
  `author` text not null,
  `ident_level` smallint(3) unsigned not null,
  `ident_state` smallint(3) unsigned not null,   
  foreign key(`ident_level`) references `level`(`ident_level`)
  on delete cascade on update cascade,
  foreign key(`ident_state`) references `state`(`ident_state`)
  on delete cascade on update cascade  
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `lessons` (
  `ident_lesson` smallint(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `page` int(11) unsigned not null,
  `title` varchar(100) not null,
  `url` varchar(100) not null unique,    
  `status` smallint(1) not null,  
  `ident_video` int(11) unsigned not null,   
   foreign key (`ident_video`) references `video`(`ident_video`)
   on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE coments(
  `ident_coment` smallint(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `title` varchar(255) not null,
  `coment` text not null,
  `vote` float(3) not null,         
  `ident_video` int(11) unsigned not null,
  `ident_user` int(11) unsigned not null,      
  `status` smallint(1) unsigned not null,
   foreign key (`ident_video`) references `video`(`ident_video`)
   on delete cascade on update cascade,
   foreign key(`ident_user`) references `user`(`ident_user`)
   on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Comment: La segunda subconsulta está retornando dos datos y usted los está intentando meter en una sola columna, ese es el error.

Comment: @Jonathanch entonces tengo que añadir otra subconsulta aparte? Lo he probado y así si funciona, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo alternativo si existe o algo más optimizado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulten he intentando reproducir tus datos.

Podrías intentar usando `JOIN` en las sub-consultas, de ese modo podrás usar las columnas que selecciones dentro.

Quedaría más o menos así (he quitado algunas columnas por razones de simplicidad):

```
SELECT v.title, v.icon, lv.level, ls.total_lessons, c.avg_vote, c.votos
FROM video_20180116 v  
LEFT JOIN
    (
         SELECT ident_video, COUNT(*) total_lessons
            FROM lessons_20180116 GROUP BY ident_video
    )    ls ON (v.ident_video = ls.ident_video)

LEFT JOIN
    (   
        SELECT AVG(vote) avg_vote, ident_video, COUNT(*) votos
        FROM coments_20180116 GROUP BY ident_video
    )   c ON (v.ident_video = c.ident_video)

LEFT JOIN level_20180116 lv on v.ident_level = lv.ident_level
WHERE v.ident_state=? ORDER BY v.ident_video DESC LIMIT 5;
```

---

### Prueba de concepto

[**<kbd>VER DEMO EN REXTESTER</kbd>**](http://rextester.com/DFRKF99781)

```
CREATE TABLE `level_20180116` (
  `ident_level` smallint(3) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `level` varchar(15) not null
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `state_20180116` (
  `ident_state` smallint(3) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `state` varchar(15) not null
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `video_20180116` (
  `ident_video` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  
  `title` varchar(255) not null,
  `icon` varchar(100) not null,        
  `ident_level` smallint(3) unsigned not null,
  `ident_state` smallint(3) unsigned not null,   
  foreign key(`ident_level`) references `level_20180116`(`ident_level`)
  on delete cascade on update cascade,
  foreign key(`ident_state`) references `state_20180116`(`ident_state`)
  on delete cascade on update cascade  
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `lessons_20180116` (
  `ident_lesson` smallint(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `title` varchar(100) not null,
  -- `status` smallint(1) not null,  
  `ident_video` int(11) unsigned not null,   
   foreign key (`ident_video`) references `video_20180116`(`ident_video`)
   on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE coments_20180116(
  `ident_coment` smallint(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  `title` varchar(255) not null,
  -- `coment` text not null,
   `vote` float(3) not null,         
  `ident_video` int(11) unsigned not null,
  -- `ident_user` int(11) unsigned not null,      
  -- `status` smallint(1) unsigned not null,
   foreign key (`ident_video`) references `video_20180116`(`ident_video`)
   on delete cascade on update cascade -- ,
   -- foreign key(`ident_user`) references `user`(`ident_user`)
   -- on delete cascade on update cascade
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_spanish_ci;

INSERT INTO level_20180116 (level) VALUES ('L1'),('L2');

INSERT INTO state_20180116 (state) VALUES ('st1'),('st2');

INSERT INTO video_20180116 (title,ident_level,ident_state,icon) VALUES 
('v1',1,1,'ic1'),
('v2',1,1,'ic2'),
('v3',2,2,'ic3')
;

INSERT INTO lessons_20180116 (title,ident_video) VALUES 
('les1',1),
('les2',1),
('les3',2)
;

INSERT INTO coments_20180116 (title,ident_video, vote) VALUES 
('com1',1, 8.5),
('com2',1, 9.2),
('com3',2, 7.6)
;

SELECT v.title, v.icon, lv.level, ls.total_lessons, c.avg_vote, c.votos
FROM video_20180116 v  
LEFT JOIN
    (
         SELECT ident_video, COUNT(*) total_lessons
            FROM lessons_20180116 GROUP BY ident_video
    )    ls ON (v.ident_video = ls.ident_video)

LEFT JOIN
    (   
        SELECT AVG(vote) avg_vote, ident_video, COUNT(*) votos
        FROM coments_20180116 GROUP BY ident_video
    )   c ON (v.ident_video = c.ident_video)

LEFT JOIN level_20180116 lv on v.ident_level = lv.ident_level
WHERE v.ident_state=1 ORDER BY v.ident_video DESC LIMIT 5;
```

#### Resultado

```
title   icon    level   total_lessons   avg_vote            votos
v2      ic2     L1      1               7,59999990463257    1
v1      ic1     L1      2               8,84999990463257    2
```

Comment: +1 Gracias por el ejemplo A.Cedano , se ve interesante, mañana lo pruebo en Localhost y te confirmo.

Comment: he probado la sentencia y se ejecuta correctamente, pero no calcula bien las subconsultas. Fíjate también en tu demo: `INSERT INTO coments_20180116` aquí podrás observar que existen un total de 3 registros, donde 2 pertenecen al identificador 1 (ident_video) y el tercero al identificador 2. En cambio, los resultados de tu ejemplo son `total_lessons 3`, `avg_vote 8.43` y `votos 3`, cuando debería ser `total_lessons 2`, `avg_vote  8.85`, etc. Luego por otro lado solo escoge un registro de la tabla `video` debería escoger **5** registros ya que existe `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: @D.Bulten ahora lo reviso. Una pregunta ¿los WHERE de las sub-consultas expresarían algún tipo de relación? En cuanto al LIMIT debe ser porque apenas inserté 3 datos de prueba.

Comment: Si los `WHERE` de las subconsultas tienen relación con la tabla `video` mediante el `ident_video` para así calcular el total de clases existente y el promedio y total de votos emitidos para cada video, y deseo mostrar 5 registros desde la tabla `video` con dichos cálculos. Modifique tu ejemplo `JOIN` por `LEFT_JOIN` y así si muestra los 3 o 5 registro existente, pero la subconsulta sigue igual, calcula solo un registro y no respeta la relación ya que calcula los totales de la tabla entero sin tener en cuenta la relación del `ident_video`.

Comment: @D.Bulten prueba agrupando en las sub-consultas, de esa manera te contará los datos diferenciados: **`JOIN
        (
             SELECT ident_video, COUNT(*) total_lessons
                FROM lessons_20180116 GROUP BY ident_video
        )    ls ON (v.ident_video = ls.ident_video)

     JOIN
        (   
            SELECT AVG(vote) avg_vote, ident_video, COUNT(*) votos
            FROM coments_20180116  GROUP BY ident_video
        )   c ON (v.ident_video = c.ident_video)`**

Comment: Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de los resultados deseados y de la manera que lo tengo funcionando: http://rextester.com/EQBS74884 y ahora voy a probar agrupando las subconsultas de tu ejemplo y te digo.

Comment: @D.Bulten agregando `GROUP BY`, como indico en el anterior comentario, arroja exactamente los resultados que estás esperando, **[he aquí el demo actualizado](http://rextester.com/DFRKF99781)**.

Comment: Correcto lo he probado en ` phpMyAdmin ` y funciona con `GROUP BY` como indicas, aun así, el `JOIN` lo he modificado por `LEFT JOIN` ya que si no existe voto no muestra dicho registro y eso no quiero, si no existe voto debe mostrar el registro igual, pero mostrando 0 votos o 0 clases. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @D.Bulten me alegro. He actualizado todo en la respuesta. Saludos.